# Asp.Net MVC Strongly Typed Collections. EditorFor not appending generated prefix

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using this [tutorial](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) at the moment.

(I believe my issue is related to strongly typed collections... by what I've been seeing on the internet, but I could be wrong)

Please bear with me. :)

I've been having this issue which I asked in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697766/mvc-uihint-parital-view-with-jquery-multiselect-dynamic-creation-issue), the answer seemed fine, but after tinkering with the code a bit more *I realized that the issue is that the fields that make use of my custom partial view, don't get a prefix added to them like the fields that use a TextBoxFor html helper*, for example. EG. When I click on add a new item, it adds it, but with the same ID as an item that's been added before, then my Javascript fails because there's two items with the same id.

**Some code to try and clarify the issue**

*Partial View*

```
@model Portal.ViewModels.Micros
@using Portal.Helpers
<div class="editorRow" style="padding-left:5px">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("micros"))
    {  
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lab_T_ID)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lab_SD_ID)         
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Result)
        <input type="button" class="deleteRow" title="Delete" value="Delete" />
    }
</div>
```

The TextBoxFor (Result) gets rendered as

```
<input id="micros_5e14bae5-df1b-4c42-9e96-573a8e52f8b2__Result" name="micros[5e14bae5-df1b-4c42-9e96-573a8e52f8b2].Result" type="text" value="">
```

Editor For get rendered as

```
<select id="Lab_SD_ID" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px; display: none; " >
      <option value="5" selected="selected">Taken at Packing 1</option>
      <option value="6">Taken at Packing 2</option>
      <option value="7">Taken at Packing 3</option>
</select>

 <button type="button" class="ui-multiselect ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" style="width: 300px; ">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s"></span><span>Taken at Packing (Winc 4/5-25d)</span></button>
```

I can include more code if its needed, there is a helper class as well (BeginCollectionItem), that I used which is located in the demo project in the tutorial as well.

I basically need to find out how "micros[5e14bae5-df1b-4c42-9e96-573a8e52f8b2]." gets appended to the input boxes as far as I can see, but have been stumped by it so far :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this works with TextBoxFor and not your custom EditorFor is because the TextBoxFor helper respects the template navigational context whereas in your editor template you have simply hardcoded a `<select>` element that doesn't even have a name. I would recommend you to use HTML helpers when generating input fields:

So replace your hardcoded select in the custom template with:

```
@model int?
@{
    var values = ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues;
}

<span>    
    @Html.DropDownList(
        "", 
        Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), 
        new { 
            multiple = "multiple",
            style = "width:" + values["comboboxWidth"] + "px",
            data_url = Url.Action((string)values["action"], (string)values["controller"]),
            data_noneselectedtext = values["noneSelectedText"],
            data_value = values["id"],
            data_text = values["description"]
        }
    )
</span>
```

Comment: thank you.. but this is getting ridiculous, feels like I've been schooled the whole day... can i buy you a beer or something?